# Skip the same element appended from loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, append

I have script to load data by callback like :

```
for(i = 0; i < allposts.length; i++){
    ....
    if ((i >= 0) && (i < 3)) {
        a += '<li><a href="'+link+'">'+post-title+'</a></li>';
    } 
}
list = a;
document.getElementById('portfolio-list').innerHTML += list;
```

When for loop end, it will append 3 posts. It mean, each loop we have like :

```
<li><a href="link1">title1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2">title2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3">title3</a></li>
```

For 2 loops (using `+= list`), for example I have :

```
<li><a href="link1">title1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2">title2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3">title3</a></li>

<li><a href="link2">title2</a></li>
<li><a href="link4">title4</a></li>
<li><a href="link5">title4</a></li>
```

You can see : `link2 is repeated`. I want catch on each loop and break if it is repeated.

It means I have result like :

```
<li><a href="link1">title1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2">title2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3">title3</a></li>

<li><a href="link4">title4</a></li>
<li><a href="link5">title5</a></li>
```

How can I do this with Javascript?

Comment: Where is `c` variable? that is causing to print link1 etc.

Comment: Store the already shown links in an array, and check if a new link is contained in that array before adding to the output.

Comment: @dbasic: sorry. it is not array. updated.

Comment: @CMate: give your answer below

Comment: I described in an answer what I thought of.

Comment: Also, I do not think it is necessary to check if `i` is nonnegative, as it cannot be.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a template I thought of in my comment previously:

```
var shownLinks = [];
for(i = 0; i < allposts.length; i++){
    ....
    if ((i >= 0) && (i < 3)) {
        // Only show a link, if it wasn't before
        if(shownLinks.indexOf(link) == -1) {
            a += '<li><a href="'+link+'">'+post-title+'</a></li>';
            // Add the link to the array
            shownLinks.push(link);
        }
    } 
}
list = a;
document.getElementById('portfolio-list').innerHTML += list;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, I dont know how you are updating `c` variable

```
var temp =[];
for(i = 0; i < allposts.length; i++){
    ....
    if ((i >= 0) && (i < 3)) {
        if(temp.indexOf(link) == -1)
        {
          a += '<li><a href="'+link+'">'+post-title+'</a></li>';
           temp.push(link);
        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var links = {};
for(i = 0; i < allposts.length; i++){
    ....
    if ((i >= 0) && (i < 3) && !links[link]) {
        a += '<li><a href="'+link+'">'+post-title+'</a></li>';
        links[link] = true;
    } 
}
```